# Python how to make class object shared across functions

Tags: python, oop

Lets say I created a class object someClassObject in function A, and threw that object into a function B:

```
functionB(someClassObject)
```

How do I retain all the modifications I've made in function B to someClassObject so I can continue using someClassObject in function A if my function B cannot return anything?

My function B is a recursive function and I can't think of anyways to have it return my someClassObject

Comment: What did you try? (Objects *are* passed as references by default, any modifications you do within `B` *should* be visible to `A`.. [see here](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference).)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that happens by default when you create a class:

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class A:
...   def __init__(self, x):
...     self.x = x
...
>>> def modA(objA):
...   objA.x = 9
... 
>>> def createA():
...   a = A(2)
...   print(a.x)
...   modA(a)
...   print(a.x)
... 
>>> createA
<function createA at 0x7ff7acee2a60>
>>> createA()
2
9
```

Answer (score 0):

if you pass a class object (generally any object) around, it stays one single object so all changes to it are visible for all references to it.

for example in

```
def B(cls):
    cls.value=2

def A():
    class C(object):
        value=1
    B(C)
    return C.value
```

A() returns 2

Answer (score 0):

I presume you meant instance of a class when you meant class object, in Python even a class is an object and you can pass them like instances.
In Python all objects are passed by reference meaning when you pass an instance to a function you only pass a reference and all changes you make to the object will be preserved.

If you meant instance of a class than the example is:

```
class Foo():

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

def functionB(foo):

    foo.x += 1
    if foo.x < 10:
        functionB(foo)



def functionA():
    some_instance_of_Foo = Foo()

    functionB(some_instance_of_Foo)

    print(some_instance_of_Foo.x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   functionA()  # 10
```